# Use ANTLR4 to get full function content with the spaces for C Language

Tags: java, antlr4

I am using ANTLR 4 to parse C codes using the grammar provide in the following link

[Grammer for C.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4)

I want the whole content of functions including all the spaces

Following is the Listener class that I am using to walk through the parse tree

```
public class CListnerImpl extends CBaseListener{

@Override
public void enterFunctionDefinition(FunctionDefinitionContext ctx) {
    System.out.println("Function name: " + ctx.declarator().directDeclarator().directDeclarator().getText());;
    System.out.println(ctx.compoundStatement().blockItemList().getText());
}
```

But for this code I am getting the function content without any whitespaces like

> Function name: sumOfCubes
>   intd,sum=0;while(n!=0){d=n%10;n/=10;sum+=d*d*d;}returnsum;

I want the output like

> Function name: sumOfCubes
>   int d,sum=0;while(n!=0){d=n%10;n/=10;sum+=d*d*d;}return sum;

It is also ok if I get the code with all the indentations too

Comment: Have you been notified of my update ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping whitespace and newlines depends on how you define the corresponding lexer rule. With this rule :

```
WS : [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip ;
```

whitespace is thrown away, whereas with this rule :

```
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
```

it is kept and available in `getText()`.

With these modifications of C.g4 :

```
compilationUnit
@init {System.out.println("C last update 0531");}
@after {System.out.println($text);}
    :   translationUnit? EOF
    ;
```

and

```
Whitespace
    :   [ \t]+
//        -> skip
        -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

Newline
    :   (   '\r' '\n'?
        |   '\n'
        )
//        -> skip
        -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

and this input in file t.text :

```
int sumOfCubes() {
    int d, sum = 0;
    while (n != 0)
        { d = n % 10;
          n /= 10;
          sum += d;
        }
    return sum;
}
```

I obtain the following result :

```
$ grun C compilationUnit -diagnostics t.text
C last update 0531
int sumOfCubes() {
    int d, sum = 0;
    while (n != 0)
        { d = n % 10;
          n /= 10;
          sum += d;
        }
    return sum;
}
```

**Java listener**

File `CMyListener.java` :

```
public class CMyListener extends CBaseListener {
    CParser parser;
    public CMyListener(CParser parser) { this.parser = parser; }

    public void exitCompilationUnit(CParser.CompilationUnitContext ctx) {
        System.out.println(parser.getTokenStream().getText(ctx));
    }
}
```

Test program, file `test_c.java` :

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRFileStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class test_c {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRFileStream(args[0]);
        CLexer lexer = new CLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        CParser parser = new CParser(tokens);
        ParseTree tree = parser.compilationUnit();
        System.out.println("parsing ended");
        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        CMyListener my_listener = new CMyListener(parser);
        System.out.println(">>>> about to walk");
        walker.walk(my_listener, tree);
    }
}
```

Execution :

```
$ javac CMyListener.java
$ javac test_c.java 
$ java test_c t.text 
C last update 0531
int sumOfCubes() {
    int d, sum = 0;
    while (n != 0)
        { d = n % 10;
          n /= 10;
          sum += d;
        }
    return sum;
}
parsing ended
>>>> about to walk
int sumOfCubes() {
    int d, sum = 0;
    while (n != 0)
        { d = n % 10;
          n /= 10;
          sum += d;
        }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: After generating the parser and lexer from the antlr4 tool, I am still not able to access the whitespaces in the Listner class. As per as my understanding the method getText() is only accessing the DEFAULT_CHANNEL and is not getting text from the HIDDEN channel

Comment: `getText()` for a token doesn't check the channel. If you are able to get a hidden token you can also get its text.

Comment: @MikeLischke Correct, I have just edited to add a Java listener and test.